Powershell script with runspace
I have a script that uses windows forms and runspace. I can't realize that after clicking on "Clean Now" button my gif picture would keep rotating and after ExitCode 0 I would get Show-SuccessForm (function in my code) but Show-SuccessForm just refuses to appear. I'm sure that ExitCode 0 is visible in debugging  What could be the reason?
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Create the form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Periodic Control"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 300)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.TopMost = $true
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
$form.MaximizeBox = $false
$form.MinimizeBox = $false

# Create the exclamation icon
$iconLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$iconLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(32, 32)
$iconLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$iconLabel.Image = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Exclamation.ToBitmap()
$form.Controls.Add($iconLabel)

# Determine the text based on system language
$language = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName
switch ($language) {
    "ru" {
       # $text = 
    }
    "uk" {
       # $text = 
    }
    default {
        $text =  "text"
    }
}

# Create the notification text
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360, 100)
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50, 10)
$label.Text = $text
$form.Controls.Add($label)

# Create the timer label
$timerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$timerLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360, 30)
$timerLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50, 120)
$form.Controls.Add($timerLabel)

$timeLeft = 60 * 60  # 60 minutes in seconds

# Create the progress bar
$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, 30)
$progressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50, 150)
$progressBar.Minimum = 0
$progressBar.Maximum = $timeLeft
$progressBar.Value = $timeLeft
$form.Controls.Add($progressBar)

# Function to update the timer
function Update-Timer {
    $global:timeLeft -= 1
    $minutes = [math]::Floor($global:timeLeft / 60)
    $seconds = $global:timeLeft % 60
    $timerLabel.Text = "Time remaining: $minutes minutes $seconds seconds"
    $progressBar.Value = $global:timeLeft

    if ($global:timeLeft -le 0) {
        $timer.Stop()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Cleaning started")
        # Add script for actual cleaning here
    }
}

# Create the timer
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 1000
$timer.Add_Tick({
    Update-Timer
})
$timer.Start()

# Initial timer setup
Update-Timer

# Create the "Clean Now" button
$button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, 200)
$button.Text = "Clean Now"
$form.Controls.Add($button)

# Create the spinner PictureBox
$spinner = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$spinner.AutoSize = $true
$spinner.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, 100)
$SpinnergifLink = 'C:\Windows\Temp\Spinner.gif'
$Spinnerimg = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($SpinnergifLink)
$spinner.Image = $Spinnerimg
$spinner.Visible = $false
$form.Controls.Add($spinner)

# Create the processing label
$processingLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$processingLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, 30)
$processingLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100, 60)
$processingLabel.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Bold", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$processingLabel.Text = "Clean files processing..."
$processingLabel.Visible = $false
$form.Controls.Add($processingLabel)

# Function to handle cleaning process
function Run-CleanProcess {
     
        $spinner.Visible = $true
        $processingLabel.Visible = $true
        $label.Visible = $false
        $timerLabel.Visible = $false
        $progressBar.Visible = $false
        $button.Visible = $false
   

    $scriptBlock = {
        $StartClearFiles = Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass", "-File C:\Windows\Temp\ClearJob.ps1" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
        return $StartClearFiles.ExitCode
        
    }

    $runspace = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock)
    $asyncResult = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
    $timerCheck = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    $timerCheck.Interval = 500  # Check every 500 milliseconds
    $timerCheck.Add_Tick({ 
        if($asyncResult.IsCompleted -eq $true) {
            $exitCode = $runspace.EndInvoke($asyncResult)
            $runspace.runspace.dispose()
            $runspace.dispose()
            if ($exitcode -eq 0) {
                Show-SuccessForm
            }
            else {
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Cleaning failed.")
            }
            }
        }) 
}

# Function to show success message
function Show-SuccessForm {
    $successForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $successForm.Text = "Success"
    $successForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300, 150)
    $successForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $successForm.TopMost = $true
    $successForm.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
    $successForm.MaximizeBox = $false
    $successForm.MinimizeBox = $false

    $successLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $successLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260, 50)
    $successLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 20)
    $successLabel.Text = "Success"
    $successForm.Controls.Add($successLabel)

    $okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
    $okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100, 80)
    $okButton.Text = "OK"
    $okButton.Add_Click({
        $successForm.Close()
    })
    
    $successForm.Controls.Add($okButton)

    [void]$successForm.ShowDialog()
}

$button.Add_Click({
    $timer.Stop()
    Run-CleanProcess
})

# Form closing event handler to prevent closing
$form.Add_FormClosing({
    $_.Cancel = $false  # Cancel form closing
})

# Show the form
[void]$form.ShowDialog()


I tried using while but it caused the form to stop updating and my picture hangs up
 $scriptBlock = {
        $StartClearFiles = Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass", "-File C:\Windows\Temp\ClearJob.ps1" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
        return $startClearFiles.ExitCode
        
    }
  
   $runspace = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($scriptBlock)
   $asyncResult = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
   while ($asyncResult.IsCompleted -notcontains $true) {}
   $exitCode = $runspace.EndInvoke($asyncResult)
   
   $runspace.Dispose()
   
   
   if ($exitcode -eq 0) {
    Show-SuccessForm
    $form.Add_FormClosing({
        $_.Cancel = $false  # Enable form closing
    })
    $form.Close()

   }


What is starting $timerCheck?

As a note, Timers that don't act as child Components (are not added to the IComponent container of a Form), are not automatically disposed when the Form closes

There’s too much code to go through in detail, but this “busy wait” isn’t ideal - while ($asyncResult.IsCompleted -notcontains $true) {} (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). You probably want a short sleep inside the body of the while or something…
